# List channel messages does not return full list of messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am not sure if this is a behavior by design or a bug. The Teams UI currently shows 5 messages from `8/29/2018` to `3/10/2019`.  I want to retrieve all of these messages with the `Graph API`.

Here's what I have done in succession:

- `GET beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages` returns 3 messages, 4 count, and a `nextLink`.
- `GET nextLink` returns 0 messages, 0 count, and a `nextLink`
- `GET nextLink` return 2 messages, 2 count, no `nextLink`.

If I interact with one of the messages on the last page (ie. replying to one), it moves that message to the first page.  `"Liking"` or bookmarking a message does not impact the return ordering of that specific message.

The results are like so:

```
1. Page 1: 4 messages, 4 count, nextLink
2. Page 2: 0 messages, 0 count, nextLink
3. Page 3: 1 message, 1 count, no nextLink
```

Should page 2 not be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages` returns messages in the order they would be displayed in **Microsoft Teams**. So yes, it's expected that adding a reply will reorder the messages, while likes & bookmarks do not.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.  What about a page with no messages but contains a nextLink (ie. page 2) to a page with more messages be expected behaviour (ie. page 3)?

Comment: One of the quirks we currently have is we don't return control messages ("Bob has added Fred to the team"), but we do include them in the message counts. So if you're reading a channel with control messages, that's probably what's going on.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you! Maybe this can be included over at learn.microsoft.com - I'll make a comment over there. A `(messages = await messages.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0)` would stop paging before the end.